# How does the static keyword work in Java?

Tags: java

I'm reading [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) from the begining and I have a question about `static` keyword on fields or variables. As `Java` said [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> **`Class Variables (Static Fields)`** A class variable is any field declared with the static modifier; this tells the compiler that there is exactly one copy of this variable in existence, regardless of how many times the class has been instantiated. A field defining the number of gears for a particular kind of bicycle could be marked as static since conceptually the same number of gears will apply to all instances.

With that, I guess that if you have an object (in this case, an instance of the class `Bicycle`) and a field inside of it that its `static` then, independently of if you are refearing to `bicycle1` or `bicycle2`, the field that its static will have the same value. Am I wrong or I understand it well?

I mean, if I have:

```
Bicycle bicycle1 = new Bicycle();
Bicycle bicycle2 = new Bicycle();
```

and in the class `Bicycle` I have a `static` field like:

```
class Bicycle{
   static int gears;

   //Methods to set and get gears
}
```

And in the `bicycle1` I set the value of gears to seven:

```
bicycle1.setGears(7);
```

then if I try to get the value of gears in `bicycle2` I should get the same value as I set on `bicycle1`, right?

```
System.out.println(bicycle2.getGears()); //7
```

Well, here is where I have the doubt because as `Java` said in the quote that I put above:

> this tells the compiler that there is exactly one copy of this variable in existence

Where is this copy stored? How the objects access to that copy? When is this copy created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How JVM handles static variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229714/how-jvm-handles-static-variable)

Comment: BTW you should usually not call static methods/attributes from instances. I don't know why it is allowed by the compiler

Comment: @Dici Can you explain me the problem that it could generate if I use them please?

Comment: @Error404 I think it is just misleading. The compiler raises a warning when you do this.

Comment: @Dici It's why I put this question. To know how it works and then could consider to use it or not :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Where is this copy stored?**

The copy (static variable) is stored in the Permanent Generation section, but if you use Java8 the Permanent Generation section no longer exists.
The static variables and static methods are part of the reflection data which are class-related data and not instance-related.

**How do the objects access that copy?**

Every instance of class (object) that you have created has a reference to the class.

**When is this copy created?**

It is created at runtime when the class is loaded: this is done by the classloader of the JVM when the class is first referenced.

***Static variables belong to the class, and not to instances of the class.***
Your intuition is right - you have only one copy regardless of how many object you create.

You can access a static variable using the name of the class, like in this example:

```
class Static {

    static int staticField;

}

public class UseStatic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Static.staticField);

    }
}
```

***The static fields are useful to create some kind of class constants.***

Finally, to easily initialize a static field of a specific class you can use [Static Initialization Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

*Sources*: University course on java, [java official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/)

Comment: Clear and complete. Thanks! Just a doubt: when you say "have a reference to the class" do you refer that it has access to the Permanent Generation section?

Comment: *"if you use Java8 the Permanent Generation section not longer exists"* ... I don't believe this is correct.  Rather, since Java 8 the PermGen size is automatically managed and administrators no longer have to concern themselves with tuning it. "*Every instance of class(object) that you have created have a reference to the class.*" ... no idea what this really means.

Comment: Yes, the reference has access to the Permanent Generation section. But the PermGen section has been removed in Java8 and has been replaced by Metaspace, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8/23388882#23388882)

Answer (score 3):

> With that, I guess that if you have an object (in this case, an
>   instance of the class Bicycle) and a field inside of it that its
>   static then, independently of if you are refearing to bicycle1 or
>   bicycle2, the field that its static will have the same value. Am I
>   wrong or I understand it well?

When you instantiate a class in Java for the first time, the JVM creates *two things*:

- an instance.  A set of non-static fields is allocated onto the heap for *each* of the instances that you create.  These instance fields are separate from all other instances (and are used to represent their object's state).
- a Class object.  Every class in Java has one, and only one, Class object ... no matter how many instances of it that are created.  For example, the Class object for class `String` is `Class<String>` (which is expressed as a literal as `String.class`).  You can think of the static fields of a class as belonging to the Class object.  The lifecycle of Class objects is independent of the lifecycle of class instances; Class objects exist for as long as the JVM process is running (therefore, their static fields also exist that long).

Since a class has only one Class object, and since all instances of a class share that same Class object, the static fields of a class are shared by all the class instances that exist.

In general, it is useful to think of the `static` keyword as meaning "independent of any instance":

- a static field belongs to the Class object and not to any instance
- a static method is invoked through the Class object and has no direct access to any instance
- a static member class instance is not dependent on any other instance

Answer (score 1):

static variables in java are stored in the class, you don't need to create a instance of it to access them.

```
class Bicycle{
   public static int gears = 7;

   //Methods to set and get gears
}
```

You can access the static method like this

```
Bicycle.gears;
```

So, there's just one Bicycle class declared on java, when you instantiate a class it's create one instance of bicycle with all static attributes declared.

Comment: Yes I know that I only need one instance to the class `Bicycle` if I just want to access to the `static` variable. It just was an example of what I understand about the `Java tutorials` and that, if I have two instances (objects) of the same class, the value will be the same in both objects (without seting the value directly in the second one). So what I want to know are the questions that I put at the bottom of my question. When and where the copy it's created and how the objects access to that copy. I mean if you have more than one objects of a class that have the same `static` value.

Comment: @Error404 What you need to understand is that `static` variables are not part of objects. Ever. They're part of a *class*, stored in the *class*, and accessed through the *class*.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is this copy stored?

Static variables are stored in some static storage (in permgen, I believe), you should not bother about it.

> When is this copy created?

They are created when class is accessed first time (loaded by class loader) and never deleted (unless class is unloaded)

> How the objects access to that copy?

Instance has reference to its class, and class has reverence to all its variables. How exactly C structures are laid in memory is implementation-specific detail.

Since static vars are bound to class, not instance, you do not even need to instantiate class to access them. `MyClass.myStaticVar` is ok.