# How non static inner class can be called using outer class name

Tags: java

```
public class InnerTest {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        A.B.print();
    }
}

class A {
    static class B {
        static void print() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

How can i call static class B using class name A although class A is not static

Comment: Why do you think `class A` should be `static`?

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to the class to be static or not, it is related the static keyword in the **method**.

take a look about [How static keyword exactly works in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417953/how-static-keyword-exactly-works-in-java) also read this article [Java – Static Class, Block, Methods and Variables](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-class-block-methods-variables/)

Answer (score 1):

One more aspect how to explain this:

`class` itself is not `static` or `non static` it is just a `class`.

You anyway can use `static` keyword only  with `class` members. If you would try to declare `InnerTest` as `static` you would have an error that might look like this (so assuming it is not static nested class to some other class)

> Illegal modifier for the class InnerTest; only public, abstract &
>   final are permitted

`static` nested `class` can be used as in question because it does not require access to any instance member of `InnerTest`. In other words it can access `static` members and only those.

If it needs access to `non static` members then it can not be `static` and the way to call would be like `new InnerTest().new B()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword is used to modify a member of a class. When a member is modified with `static`, it can be accessed directly using the enclosing class' name, instead of using an instance of the enclosing class like you would with a non-static member.

The inner class `Inner` below is a member of the class `Outer`:

```
class Outer {
    static class Inner {}
}
```

Therefore, `Inner` can be accessed like this:

```
Outer.Inner
```

`Outer` don't need to/cannot be modified by `static` because it is not a member of a class. It is a class existing in the global scope. To access it, you just write its name - `Outer`. It does not make sense for it to be non-static because it has no enclosing class. If it were non-static, how are you supposed to access it?

Answer (score 0):

To use the correct terminology, class B is not an *inner* class; it is a *static nested class*. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html for the definitions of the various types of nested class.

The important keyword is the `static` keyword in front of the definition of class B. It does not matter whether class A is static or not. In fact, it wouldn't make sense to put `static` in front of class A's definition.

Because class B is declared static, it doesn't keep a reference to an instance of class A.