# Two constructors and static String variable

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I have a rather confusing class, in which I don't understand why `superUser` is always being printed. I know that if I would have written `private String username = "user"`, then I would have been able to call it in my `main` method like that: `System.out.println(o1.username)`. In my case the above would also print out superUser, because it is static. But I don't really get it.. is it because Java reads the code completely first and realizes that I have a second object `o2`, which has its own constructor, where the argument is assigned to the local variable `username`?

What I don't get is why `System.out.println(o1.getUsername());` prints superUser.

```
public class PrintMe {

   private static String username = "user";
   private int password = 1234;
   public PrintMe(){}
   public PrintMe(String username){
       PrintMe.username = username;
       this.password = 5678;
   }

   public void changePassword(int password){
       System.out.println("The old password of " + this.getUsername() +
            " was " + this.password);
       this.password = password;
   }

   public String getUsername(){
       return PrintMe.username;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       PrintMe o1 = new PrintMe();
       PrintMe o2 = new PrintMe("superUser");
       System.out.println(o1.getUsername()); // superUser
       System.out.println(o1.password); // 1234
       System.out.println(o2.getUsername()); // superUser
       System.out.println(o2.password); // 5678
       o1.changePassword(9000); // The old password of superUser was 1234
       System.out.println(o1.getUsername()); // superUser
       System.out.println(o1.password); // 9000
       System.out.println(o2.getUsername()); // superUser
       System.out.println(o2.password); // 5678
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417953/how-does-the-static-keyword-work-in-java)? BTW, Java is not difficult ;)

Comment: Nothing about your output is unexpected.  Can you direct us to the exact line(s) which are confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `username` is static. This means that there is ever only one instance of that variable, no matter how many instances of `PrintMe` you have. The variable `username` is shared between all instances of `PrintMe`. This means that here:

```
   PrintMe o1 = new PrintMe();
   PrintMe o2 = new PrintMe("superUser");
```

The second line overwrites the `username` variable to be `superUser`. Since calling `getUsername` on either `o1` or `o2` returns the same variable, you get `superUser` as output.

To fix this, simply remove the word `static` from the variable declaration:

```
private String username = "user";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `username` is static it is not a property of the instance (`o1`, `o2`) but of the class. When the constructor `PrintMe(String)` is used the static `username` is modified. So when `o2` is created the `username` is changed to "superUser". If you print `o1.getUsername()` before creating `o2` you would get "user", afterwards you get "superUser". Remove the `static` modifier for the `username` and you will get the expected behavior.